# Django: Access to re_path-variables in template

Tags: django

How can I access to variables in "re_path" (e.g. "username") in template?

example:

```
re_path(r'user/mieteinheit/(?:(?P<wohnungsgruppenname>\w+)/)?$', views.mieteinheit,name="mieteinheit"),
```

EDIT:

part of views.py:

```
def mieteinheit(request, wohnungsgruppenname):
    #prüfe hier ob der Nutzer überhaupt die Wohnung besitzt und was sehen darf!!
    print("wohnungsgruppenname: "+str(wohnungsgruppenname))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WohnungseinheitenForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        tmp = request.GET.get('wohnungsgruppenname')
        if tmp is not None:
            x=1
            for y in Wohnungsgruppe.objects.filter():
                if y.wohnungsgruppenname == request.GET['wohnungsgruppenname']: 
                    break 
                else: 
                    x=x+1
            form = WohnungseinheitenForm(request.POST or None,initial={'wohnungsgruppe': x})
        else:
            #raise Http404
            form = WohnungseinheitenForm(instance=Wohnungseinheiten.objects.get(id=str(wohnungsgruppenname)))# instance=Wohnungseinheiten.objects.get(id=tr(wohnungsgruppenname))
    template = loader.get_template('Immo/user/mieteinheit.html')
    context = {"wohnungsgruppenname":wohnungsgruppenname,"form": form}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

Comment: That entirely depends on the view.

Comment: The view is the logic that should pass data to the template, so you should "pass it in the view" to the template render engine.

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: Since you already pass the variable in your context, simply use `{{ wohnungsgruppenname }}` in your template.